# Can you find such a function? $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ doesnt exist

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

We want to find two functions $f,g$ such that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)=\lim_{x\to \infty}g(x) = \infty$, $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 10$, but $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ doesnt exist.

I'm having difficulties coming up with an answer. I can't really tell you what I tried since all I did was try and come up with functions that maybe could somehow satisfy this, just guessing, failed so far. Would appreciate a hint in the right direction or the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: Let $g$ by linear and $f$ be linear $+$ an oscillation terms that is small in value, but not in derivative.

Comment: something along the lines of $cos(1/x)$?

Comment: @OriaGruber That function is almost constant away from $0$.

Comment: @OriaGruber, since the limit is to be taken as $x\to \infty$ you may try $\cos(e^t)$ instead of $\cos(1/x)$.

Comment: How about $f(x) = x+cos(1/x)$? the derivative is $1-\frac{1}{x^2} sin(1/x)$. that has no limit i think

Comment: @OriaGruber The derivative of that function tends to $1$ at infinity.

Comment: $f(x) = x + \cos (e^x)$?

Comment: @OriaGruber Sure, that works.